# List of tuples calculate min-max date difference from tuples

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, tuples

I have a list of tuples which has time stamp in each of the tuple, I wanted to get the latest time stamp - old timestamp for every 1st position of the tuple.

```
example_out put  = [(2038, A, [Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00')- Timestamp('2010-02-20 00:00:00')]),(2038,B , [Timestamp('2017-01-24 00:00:00')- Timestamp('2017-02-20 00:00:00')])] It has to do for all the IDS

abc = [(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-01-27 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-01-30 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-02-02 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-02-06 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-02-11 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-02-18 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'A', Timestamp('2010-02-20 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-01-24 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-01-27 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-01-30 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-02-02 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-02-06 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-02-11 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-02-18 00:00:00')),
(2038, 'B', Timestamp('2017-02-20 00:00:00')),
(2120, 'A', Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00'))]
```

is this the right way to do it put all the ids into a list and then calculate the min and max dates ?

```
d = {}
l = []

    for r in abc:
        l.append(r)
        if r[0] not in d:
            d[r[0]] = r[1],[r[2]]

    print(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `pandas`, you can utilize `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(abc, columns=['Year', 'Category', 'Date'])\
        .groupby(['Year', 'Category'])['Date'].agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   Year Category    Date
0  2038        A 27 days
1  2038        B 27 days
2  2120        A  0 days
```